# How can I query data from my Cosmos DB in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, api, chart.js, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query my data in my Cosmos DB in Angular in hopes to populate charts (from chart.js) to show the data. I am unsure about how you can query data in angular. Right now, I have some basic components with APIs to get basic information from the database, but I do not know how to query it.

Comment: Have you tired @azure/cosmos package? https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB offers a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/) to access documents. For example:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CosmosDBService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    get(id: string) {
      return this.http.get(
        `https://${account}.documents.azure.com/dbs/${db}/colls/${collection}/docs/${id}`);
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to take care of access control, and set the right auth headers to the requests (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources)